# List the differences between two dataframe columns ignoring case

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare columns from 2 dataframes and return the difference, ignoring case. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data1={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan']}
    data2={'Name':['karan','Rohit','Sahil']}

    df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
    df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)

    print(list(set(df1['Name']).difference(df2['Name'])))
```

This code prints `['Karan', 'Aryan']`. How do I modify this to ignore case so that `karan` and `Karan` are recognized as a match and only `Aryan` is returned?

I don't want to use the following because it returns `aryan` and I want to maintain the capitalization of the row. In my real case, they are not first names so it isn't as easy as making the first letter capitalized again after taking the difference.

```
    print(list(set(df1['Name'].str.lower()).difference(df2['Name'].str.lower())))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To perform a case insensitive comparison, use [`str.casefold`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.casefold.html):

```
print(list(set(df1['Name'].str.casefold()).difference(df2['Name'].str.casefold())))
```

If you want to keep the original case use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1.loc[~df1['Name'].str.casefold().isin(df2['Name'].str.casefold()), 'Name'].unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['Aryan'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my original question to add that using a function like lower() returns 'aryan', but I would like for it to return 'Aryan' with original capitalization from the first list if possible.

Comment: @Anna see the second approach for that